# Are these duplicate or redundant MX and A records?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I just moved DNS from a webhost/registrar to CloudFlare, which imported all the existing DNS records. My question is that it seems like there are some unused DNS records from the old host that could be deleted, but I'm not sure.

The website is hosted at WPEngine, and for that DNS, I have a CNAME of the name of the domain with a value of the WPE server, as well as a CNAME of WWW with the same WPE server value. That is all standard practice for WPE with DNS hosted at Cloudflare; the use of WPEngine as a host predates the DNS move to CloudFlare, and I moved the site to WPEngine, and everything - the site, FTP - works fine at WPEngine.

I also have the standard MX records for Google mail, i.e. aspmx.l.google.com, alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, etc., and a CNAME for `mail` that points to ghs.googlehosted.com. These MX records and the use of Google for email predates the DNS move to Cloudflare.

There are various TXT records for domain verification and SPF, which I will leave in place.

But I also have A records with the names of `email`, `ftp`, `imap`, `mx`, `pop`, `smtp` and `webmail`, all of which point to several different IP addresses which are not Google or WPEngine, but are all to the same third-party webhost and email service called bizland.com.

Are all those A records redundant? Are they even being used? Are they lower priority than the Google MX records and as a result are not used? IMAP and POP are options for Google mail and configured at Google, not in DNS. And FTP must be handled by the CNAME to WPEngine, as FTP works.

Comment: We have no way to know which hosts are in use and not. You might point ftp and www to same host, but there might be applications using ftp while web browsers use www. When i setup webserives i try to separate them on different dns domain names, Even its the same server hosting them. This is so it Will be easier to separate things later if needed. So you Will have to get some documentation on what your domain is used for and what the different hosts are for.

Comment: According to my DNS, there are only two hosts in use: WPEngine and Google. The third host appears to be unused; that's my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving enough details, but in short:

- if there are multiple `A` records for the same name, only at the DNS level, each one will get, on average, the same number of queries, so it is load balancing, not failover. Depending on the application using those records, it may retry with the next one if one does not work, but that is not generally guaranteed (nor given by the DNS protocol) and it will incur at least a delay
- if there are multiple `MX` record for the same name, then it depends on the value of the priority field:

  - if it is the same value for all records then you are back at previous step, it should get a load balancing behaviour
  - otherwise, per the standard, `MX` records are used from lowest priority value to highest, so compliant MTAs first try (only) the lowest one, and if it fails then they go further to the next highest one and so on. This is guaranteed per the RFCs on SMTP and `MX` records definition.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. There's no priority that I can see on the A records with the names of mx, so I'm thinking the Google MX records take precedence anyway. And they are pointed at a host that isn't used by the domain or the domain owner. So it seems like the Google MX records are only being used, unless that other host simply drops the queries, since there is nothing at the host to use the queries.